# Why Hotelling's $T^2$ is taught in the book but it is not used anywhere so far?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, anova, multivariate-analysis, hotelling-t2

I have seen various multivariate statistics book covering Hotelling $T^2$ statistics. However, when reading medical journals and papers, it does not show up anywhere.

Q1:Is this test of any practical value? All I can tell is that it detects multivariate mean of multi-groups equal to something. I could also use ANOVA contrast matrices instead. Hotelling will require asymptotic result. So I would guess it has lower power compared to ANOVA contrasts as ANOVA may not be sensitive to deviation from normality in small sample case.

Q2:Why is it still covered in multivariate statistics book, even if it is not seen a lot in journals and papers?

Comment: For your Q2, I might turn the question around to ask why practitioners are still using univariate tests when multivariate tests are well-established.

Comment: @Dave Simple univariate test is easy and multiple adjustment is easy. I guess Hotelling's $T^2$'s rejection region might be more stringent compare to those of adjusted univariate testing. Multivariate testing for point should really use contrasting from my perspective.

Comment: The advantage of the multivariate test is that it takes advantage of the correlations between the marginal distributions. If you’re unclear about how this happens, you might consider posting a question. I have in mind a plot I can make that will illustrate this. (I had the same question in my multivariate class, why we didn’t just test the margins. The example I would post mimics what my professor said that I found so helpful.)

Comment: @Dave I would be interested in that as I am not aware how it take advantage of correlation of marginalized variables. I will edit my question.

Comment: This question is totally valid. If you are confused about how the multivariate test works, please post it as a separate question. Your Q1 and Q2 are reasonable to post together. Q3 kind of warrants it’s own question and answer (and I suspect has been addressed before on Cross Validated).

Comment: @Dave I have posted here. Thanks for clarifying it. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/586738/why-multivariate-test-takes-advantage-of-the-correlations-between-the-marginal

Comment: One reason is that $T^2$ can detect a difference that is not of interest.   For example on might test whether a drug lowers either systolic or diastolic blood pressure.  If the drug changed only the pulse pressure (SBP - DBP) $T^2$ may detect that but it may not be of clinical interest.

Comment: The applications I'm familiar with are in Control Charts for Quality control, here's what appears to be an elementary intro: https://medium.com/swlh/multivariate-quality-control-charts-t2-chart-and-ellipse-chart-405779dbf452