# Why "multivariate test takes advantage of the correlations between the marginal distributions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, hotelling-t2

It is claimed (in a comment [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/586735/247274)) that "The advantage of the multivariate test is that it takes advantage of the correlations between the marginal distributions". Why this is the case for Hotelling's $T^2$?

Comment: You quote a comment, which is a bit risky since comments tend not to be as well considered as answers.  In this case I suspect the commenter intended to write *conditional* rather than *marginal.*  Why not post a comment of your own in that thread to ask for clarification?

Comment: Why stop at Hotelling $T^2?$ Please note the necessity of multivariate analysis - the general purpose, what it intends to do.